# Latest Chrome update messed up Sencha Touch 2.0.0 layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, sencha-touch, sass

After the July 31, 2012 update of Chrome to 21.0.1180.60, my app built with the Sencha Touch 2.0.0 started having many issues when viewed in the browser. 
among them :
background images do not appear - or do appear but with wrong size.
All titles are displayed with ellipsis.
responsiveness is terrible(!)
I tried updating Sencha to its latest release and it introduces even more problems.

Has anyone had an issue with the latest version of Chrome?

any help is welcome

Comment: Yeah I also face same issue so I just degrade my browser and avoid  Dev or beta Browser or use those browser who support full Webkit

Comment: Yeah this annoys me too, gotta use safari now >.<

Comment: Why -1? I also degraded for now, but it is a public website so it's a production problem!

Comment: Yes, I have lots of issues with masks and the screen not redrawing itself. Lots of visual artefacts being left behind after a mask has been displayed. Reverted to using Safari for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with the ellipsis in the title after restarting Chrome on my desktop and having itself updated to v21.
It seems to be a CSS issue with Sencha Touch 2.0 which is fixed with 2.1.0 b2. See also the [Sencha Touch forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234556-Chrome-21-All-titles-are-displayed-with-ellipsis-%28ST2-2.0.1.1%29).

A workaround for now is to include the following CSS:

```
.x-title { padding:0 .3em; }
.x-title .x-innerhtml { padding: 0; }
```

Regarding the other issues I'm afraid I cannot help.

Comment: also:
old css(now broken):

`background: url(....) no-repeat center center;`

`background-size: cover;`


new css (should work):
`background-image: url(....)`
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`
`background-position: center center;`
`background-size: cover;`